# Create Git repository in a network shared path and maintain code in the repo

Tags: git

I'm trying to create a Git repository in Windows and I want the code to be maintained in a shared path. This particular shared path must contain the final code and the users should be able to fetch this code into their local machine and make desired changes. Once changes are completed they should be able to commit the code into the shared path containing the final code. I want this shared path location to act as the central repository.

Initially I tried to create a Git repository in the shared path by doing:

```
pushd \\remoteServer\git\Share\Folder\Path\.git
git init --bare
```

Then I came to my local machine and checked out the code by doing:

```
git clone \\remoteServer\git\Share\Folder\Path
```

After cloning the repository I created a new file and committed the changes using:

```
git add .
git commit -m "test"
```

It says successfully committed the code and then I tried to push the code in using below command:

```
git push origin
```

But I got an error message saying `fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.`

So I tried to push the code by using command:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Now I got the below response:

```
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 213 bytes | 71.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To //remoteServer/git/Share/Folder/Path/NewPro
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
```

But while checking the shared folder new file I created is not present in there.

I am a noobie in Git. Kindly help me in setting up a Git repo in shared path.

Comment: Did you push code after commit?

Comment: Your "upstream" is a bare repo - meaning it does not have a workarea. Clone in a new directory somewhere and the file should show up in that workarea.

Comment: That's the point of the `--bare` in `git init --bare`. This "bare" repository in the shared folders will not contains the files.

Comment: @ManthanTilva yes I have tried that too. I have updated the thread.

Comment: @NitKrish I think there is a mistake here "But I got an error message saying `git push origin` "

Comment: Thanks @Jona for pointing this out. I created this as a bare repository since I wanted this to be the central repo. But what if I need it to be my master directory and I need to maintain code in it. How  to achieve that ?

Comment: Git is decentralized. There is no "central repo". If everyone points their upstream to the same repo, you might call it the "central repo".

Comment: Okay. So can you tell me how to make the shared folder to hold all the code and be able to be checked out.

Comment: Initialize the repository without `--bare` and it will have a working folder. The recommended way, however, is to set up a clone/pull approach that pulls from the "central repo" to your server where you host the files, and not to push to the place where you host the files.

Comment: Try what @fredrik says "Clone in a new directory somewhere and the file should show up in that workarea."

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen the reason I want it to be in shared path is so that all users having access to the shared path can clone the project to their machine.

Comment: Beware of making direct modifications to the files in that working folder, however. Always update the working folder on the server **only through pushing**.

Comment: @Jona I tried clonning it somewhere else and it is working.

Comment: @NitKrish OK, good. I will write a wrapup as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were surprised not to find the files in the shared path but it's what a bare repository is about. It records the repository but it doesn't contain a working directory (you don't see the files commited).

More info on the git official documentation : [Getting Git on a Server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server)